# Porque no me reconoce el Aside

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy comenzando en este campo y me ha surgido un problema que ya no se como solucionarlo, he intentado de todo.
El aside me queda más grande que el section y no se que hacer.
Cuando voy al inspector de Google para ver que pasa, es como si el body no me reconociera el aside, es decir, queda afuera de este:
[image: Lo azul es el body]

He intentado ponerle propiedades mediante "*{}" y tampoco puedo :(

Seguro me mande alguna en el css, pero no lo encuentro, y mi página por las dudas, no es responsiva, todavia no he llegado a adaptarla

y mi código es este:

```css
body, html{font-family:sans-serif;
    background-color:  rgb(22, 22, 43);
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;}
       

/*Centrar toda la pág:*/
.pagina {width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        flex: 1;}

/*recuadro azul a la izquierda*/
aside{background-color: rgb(47, 47, 92); 
    float: left;
    width: 35%; /*era:  width: calc(20% - 20px);*/
    height: auto;            /*agregado*/
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 1px;}   /*cambiado, era auto*/

figure {display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;}


figcaption {text-align: center;}

/*Titulos del aside que estan en recuadros*/
.blanco {color: white; 
        justify-content: center;
        width: 280px;
        margin: 16px auto 16px auto;}

/*Texto de los titulos del aside*/
.blanco2 {color: white; 
            justify-content: center;
            text-align: left;
            width: 280px;
            margin: 8px auto 8px 20%;}

.itembla {color: white; 
            justify-content: center;
            text-align: left;
            width: 280px;
            margin: auto auto auto 15%;}





/*Parte derecha:*/

.contenido {float: left;
    background-color: rgb(248, 248, 252);
            width: 50%; /*era:  width: calc(80% - 80px);*/
            justify-content: left; /*era center*/
            text-align: left;
            height: 100%; /*cambiado, era margin auto*/
            padding: 20px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            border: 1px solid rgb(52, 52, 102);}

/*Titulos de la parte blanca que estan en recuadros*/
.negro1 {color: black; 
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
        width: auto;
        margin: auto}

/*Texto de los titulos de la parte blanca*/
.negro2 {color: black; 
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: left;
        width: auto;
        margin: auto auto auto 20px;}
```

```html
 <body>
            <article class="pagina">
                <aside>
                    <figure>
                        <!-- Foto carnet-->
                        <a href="./Imagen/yo.jpg" target="_blank">
                            <img 
                            src="./Imagen/yoCarnet.png"
                            alt="La imagen de perfil no se pudo cargar"
                            title="Imagen"> </a>
                        <figurecaption> <span style="color:white; font-size: 20px;"><strong>Mi nombre</strong></span></figurecaption>                                     
                    </figure>
                    
                    <br>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <!--Sobre mi-->
                            <p class="blanco"><span style="border-image: initial; border-radius: 8px; border: 1px solid white; padding: 5px;">&#x1f453; | SOBRE MI</span></p>
                            <p class="blanco"><em>xxxxxxxxxxx</em></p>
                        </div>

                        <br>

                        <div>
                            <!--Perfil-->
                            <p class="blanco"><span style="border-image: initial; border-radius: 8px; border: 1px solid white; padding: 5px;">&#128100; | PERFIL</span></p>
                            <p class="blanco2">Edad: 23 años</p>
                            <p class="blanco2">Fecha de nacimiento: 10/01/2000</p>
                            <p class="blanco2">Localidad: Córdoba</p>
                            <p class="blanco2">Nacionalidad: Argentina</p>

                        </div>

                        <br>
                        
                        <div>
                            <!--Contacto-->
                            <p class="blanco"><span style="border-image: initial; border-radius: 8px; border: 1px solid white; padding: 5px;">&#x2709; | CONTACTO</span></p>
                            <p class="blanco2">&#9743; 3541 90 9202 (Córdoba)</p>
                            <p class="blanco2">&#128386; cancal20@gmail.com</p>
                            <p class="blanco2">&#128392; Calle n°3020</p>
                        </div>

                        <br>

                        <div>
                            <!-- Idiomas-->
                            <p class="blanco"><span style="border-image: initial; border-radius: 8px; border: 1px solid white; padding: 5px;">&#x1f5e8; | IDIOMA</span></p>
                            <p class="blanco2">Ingles avanzado </p>
                            <p class="blanco2">Italiano inicial</p>
                        </div>

                        <br>

                        <div>
                            <!--Conocimientos enlistados-->
                            <p class="blanco"><span style="border-image: initial; border-radius: 8px; border: 1px solid white; padding: 5px;">&#x1f4da;  | CONOCIMIENTOS</span></p>
                            <p class="blanco2">Ofimatica</p>
                                <ul class="itembla">
                                    <li>Word</li>
                                    <li>Paquete Office</li>
                                </ul>

                            <p class="blanco2">Desarrollo</p>
                                <ul class="itembla">
                                    <li>C++</li>
                                    <li>HTML5</li>
                                </ul>
                            <p class="blanco2">Community Manager</p>
                                <ul class="itembla">
                                    <li>YouTube</li>
                                    <li>Instagram</li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </aside>

                <!--Lado izquierdo-->

                <section class="contenido">
                    
                        <!--ESTUDIOS-->
                        <div class="centrar"> 
                            <h2 class="negro1"><span class="sombra" style="border-image: initial; border-radius: 8px; border: 1px solid black; padding: 8px; ">&#x1f393;  | FORMACIÓN</span></h2>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    <span class="hideText">
                        <br> 
                        <div>
                            <h3 class="negro2">PRIMARIA</h3>
                            <ul style="color: rgb(102, 102, 218);">
                                <li><p class="item">XXX / <span style="color: rgb(107, 102, 102); font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: small;">MAR 2009 - DIC 2011.</span></p></li>
                                <li><p class="item">XXX / <span style="color: rgb(107, 102, 102); font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: small;">MAR 2012 - DIC 2013.</span></p></li>                     
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <br>

                        <div>
                            <h3 class="negro2">SECUNDARIA</h3>
                            <ul style="color: rgb(102, 102, 218);">
                                <li><p class="item">XXXX / <span style="color: rgb(107, 102, 102); font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: small;">MAR 2014 - DIC 2021.</span></p></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <br>
                        <br>

                        <div>
                            <h3 class="negro2">COMPLEMENTARIA</h3>
                            <ul style="color: rgb(102, 102, 218);">
                                <li><p class="item">XXXXX / <span style="color: rgb(107, 102, 102); font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: small;">MAR 2009 - DIC 2012.</span></p></li>
                                <li><p class="item">XXXX / <span style="color: rgb(107, 102, 102); font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: small;">MAR 2013 - DIC 2018.</span></p></li>
                                <li><p class="item">XXXX / <span style="color: rgb(107, 102, 102); font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: small;">ABR 2020 - ACT.</span></p></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>  
                    </span>
                    <div class="centrar">
                        <button class="read-more-btn">Ampliar info</button></span>
                    </div>

                </section>


            </article>
        
        <script src="./js/cv.js"></script> 


    </body>
```

Comment: Prueba con `height: max-content;` en el aside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo prefiero usar css [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/), me parece más sencillo que el flex y facilita la maquetación. Si revisas bien el código a continuación te darás cuenta que he puesto en la clase `pagina` esto:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr
```

Lo cual genera 2 columnas iguales (1fr 1fr)

```css
body, html{
font-family:sans-serif;
background-color:  rgb(22, 22, 43);
    margin:0;}
       

/*Centrar toda la pág:*/
.pagina {
    width: 50%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    justify-items: stretch;
    margin: 15px auto;
   
}

/*recuadro azul a la izquierda*/
aside{
background-color: rgb(47, 47, 92);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 0;
}   

figure {display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;}


figcaption {text-align: center;}

/*Titulos del aside que estan en recuadros*/
.blanco {color: white; 
        justify-content: center;
        width: 280px;
        margin: 16px auto 16px auto;}

/*Texto de los titulos del aside*/
.blanco2 {color: white; 
            justify-content: center;
            text-align: left;
            width: 280px;
            margin: 8px auto 8px 20%;}

.itembla {color: white; 
            justify-content: center;
            text-align: left;
            width: 280px;
            margin: auto auto auto 15%;}





/*Parte derecha:*/

.contenido {
    background-color: rgb(248, 248, 252);
  text-align: left;
            border: 1px solid rgb(52, 52, 102);}

/*Titulos de la parte blanca que estan en recuadros*/
.negro1 {color: black; 
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
        width: auto;
        margin: auto}

/*Texto de los titulos de la parte blanca*/
.negro2 {color: black; 
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: left;
        width: auto;
        margin: auto auto auto 20px;}
```

```html
<body>
            <article class="pagina">
                <aside>
                    <figure>
                        <!-- Foto carnet-->
                        <a href="./Imagen/yo.jpg" target="_blank">
                            <img 
                            src="./Imagen/yoCarnet.png"
                            alt="La imagen de perfil no se pudo cargar"
                            title="Imagen"> </a>
                        <figurecaption> <span style="color:white; font-size: 20px;"><strong>Mi nombre</strong></span></figurecaption>                                     
                    </figure>
                    
                    <br>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <!--Sobre mi-->
                            <p class="blanco"><span style="border-image: initial; border-radius: 8px; border: 1px solid white; padding: 5px;">&#x1f453; | SOBRE MI</span></p>
                            <p class="blanco"><em>xxxxxxxxxxx</em></p>
                        </div>

                        <br>

                        <div>
                            <!--Perfil-->
                            <p class="blanco"><span style="border-image: initial; border-radius: 8px; border: 1px solid white; padding: 5px;">&#128100; | PERFIL</span></p>
                            <p class="blanco2">Edad: 23 años</p>
                            <p class="blanco2">Fecha de nacimiento: 10/01/2000</p>
                            <p class="blanco2">Localidad: Córdoba</p>
                            <p class="blanco2">Nacionalidad: Argentina</p>

                        </div>

                        <br>
                        
                        <div>
                            <!--Contacto-->
                            <p class="blanco"><span style="border-image: initial; border-radius: 8px; border: 1px solid white; padding: 5px;">&#x2709; | CONTACTO</span></p>
                            <p class="blanco2">&#9743; 3541 90 9202 (Córdoba)</p>
                            <p class="blanco2">&#128386; cancal20@gmail.com</p>
                            <p class="blanco2">&#128392; Calle n°3020</p>
                        </div>

                        <br>

                        <div>
                            <!-- Idiomas-->
                            <p class="blanco"><span style="border-image: initial; border-radius: 8px; border: 1px solid white; padding: 5px;">&#x1f5e8; | IDIOMA</span></p>
                            <p class="blanco2">Ingles avanzado </p>
                            <p class="blanco2">Italiano inicial</p>
                        </div>

                        <br>

                        <div>
                            <!--Conocimientos enlistados-->
                            <p class="blanco"><span style="border-image: initial; border-radius: 8px; border: 1px solid white; padding: 5px;">&#x1f4da;  | CONOCIMIENTOS</span></p>
                            <p class="blanco2">Ofimatica</p>
                                <ul class="itembla">
                                    <li>Word</li>
                                    <li>Paquete Office</li>
                                </ul>

                            <p class="blanco2">Desarrollo</p>
                                <ul class="itembla">
                                    <li>C++</li>
                                    <li>HTML5</li>
                                </ul>
                            <p class="blanco2">Community Manager</p>
                                <ul class="itembla">
                                    <li>YouTube</li>
                                    <li>Instagram</li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </aside>

       

                <section class="contenido">
                    
                        <!--ESTUDIOS-->
                        <div class="centrar"> 
                            <h2 class="negro1"><span class="sombra" style="border-image: initial; border-radius: 8px; border: 1px solid black; padding: 8px; ">&#x1f393;  | FORMACIÓN</span></h2>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    <span class="hideText">
                        <br> 
                        <div>
                            <h3 class="negro2">PRIMARIA</h3>
                            <ul style="color: rgb(102, 102, 218);">
                                <li><p class="item">XXX / <span style="color: rgb(107, 102, 102); font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: small;">MAR 2009 - DIC 2011.</span></p></li>
                                <li><p class="item">XXX / <span style="color: rgb(107, 102, 102); font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: small;">MAR 2012 - DIC 2013.</span></p></li>                     
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <br>

                        <div>
                            <h3 class="negro2">SECUNDARIA</h3>
                            <ul style="color: rgb(102, 102, 218);">
                                <li><p class="item">XXXX / <span style="color: rgb(107, 102, 102); font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: small;">MAR 2014 - DIC 2021.</span></p></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <br>
                        <br>

                        <div>
                            <h3 class="negro2">COMPLEMENTARIA</h3>
                            <ul style="color: rgb(102, 102, 218);">
                                <li><p class="item">XXXXX / <span style="color: rgb(107, 102, 102); font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: small;">MAR 2009 - DIC 2012.</span></p></li>
                                <li><p class="item">XXXX / <span style="color: rgb(107, 102, 102); font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: small;">MAR 2013 - DIC 2018.</span></p></li>
                                <li><p class="item">XXXX / <span style="color: rgb(107, 102, 102); font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: small;">ABR 2020 - ACT.</span></p></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>  
                    </span>
                    <div class="centrar">
                        <button class="read-more-btn">Ampliar info</button></span>
                    </div>

                </section>


            </article>
        
        <script src="./js/cv.js"></script> 


    </body>
```

Comment: Le hice los cambios que me marcaste, borre cosas que pude notar que se ve que tenía de mas... Pero me daré cuenta mientras más aprenda. Lo unico que si me quedó el aside del mismo tamaño que el section... eso lo puedo cambiar de alguna forma? me gustaría que el aside sea un poco mas chico.
Nuevamente, muchas gracias!

Comment: @CandelaCalzada Que bueno haber podido ayudarte. Para que el aside se más chico solo tienes que agregarle margenes (ejemplo: margin:10px 0)